# Reindex job failing due to being victim of a deadlock, but it is the only process running at 3am..?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, maintenance

I have a reindex job in a maintenance plan which I run on every table in a given database at 3am so it won't interrupt any other work.

However it is failing and reporting the reason as being the victim of a deadlock on the tables - how can I work out what has locked the tables other than it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got the deadlock trace flags enabled (1222, etc)? These will give you a dump of the deadlock in SQL Server's ERRORLOG file (normally in the logs directory) and thus should help you get to the bottom of it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=SQL.90).aspx for more details.

It can be enabled for the current service with `DBCC TRACEON (-1, 1222)`. However if you want the traceflag to be a permanent change then you'll need to put the traceflag onto SQL Server's startup parameters (`-T1222`) and then stop and restart SQL Server.

Comment: using the 'DBCC TRACEON (-1, 1222)' method, will trace flag be enabled until the service is next restarted?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an agent job that captures the deadlock graph.
see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186385%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx